# .each() not looping all elements - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a element to carry all my account elements like so:

```
var $account_list_j = $('#account_list');
```

I add dynamic elements so the structure looks like

```
<div id="account_list">
 <div class="card account-list-item">
  <input id="group_name_0" type="text" class="form-control name" name="username" placeholder="Account name" value="">
 </div>
 <div class="card account-list-item">
  <input id="group_name_0" type="text" class="form-control name" name="username" placeholder="Account name" value="">
 </div>
</div>
```

I try and loop over the dynamic elements and return false if any of them have a value less then the minimum account name length.

```
function accounts_name_check(params) {
    var success = true;
    $account_list_j.each(function(e) {
        if($(this).find('.name').val().length < min_account_name_length && success){
            var string = 'All Accounts must have a name of at least '+min_account_name_length+ ' characters.';
            add_error_message(string);
            $(this).find('.name').addClass('is-invalid');
            success = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).find('.name').removeClass('is-invalid');
        }
    });
    return success;
}
```

It seems the the function will only check the first element in the list, then stops. The first element is the only static element (the others are populate account list div with a button). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Multiple elements in the same document with the same ID is **invalid HTML**. Fix that, and it should work.

Comment: `$('#account_list').length` will always return **1 or 0** since the selector is an id and there can only be **1** unique id in the DOM...

Comment: You can't loop trough elements with the same ID, use classnames instead

Comment: You are iterating over an object with one element in it. There’s only one #account_list

Comment: hence `$('#account_list').each(callback)` will always execute **1** callback (if the element was found) or **0** callbacks otherwise.

Comment: Source for you: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/. The query returns a single result is its default behavior. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I chopped up my html to make this question easier to read. I accidently copy-pasta'd it. They are dynamically created and they all have different ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line `var $account_list_j = $('#account_list');` to `var $account_list_j = $('.account-list-item');`

You have multiple account item list (`account-list-item`) not the multiple `#account_list`.

Comment: This seems to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need  `var $account_list_j = $('#account_list .card');` to get a list